# How to Filter table and Limit it to 1 TOP row with Dax

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm new to Power BI and Dax queries.
I have 2 tables added with 1:* relation. What I'm trying to do is to filter the second table by a foreign key and specific Key.

Example:

```
###Table1:###
ID | RunID | ...[Other columns]

###Table2:###
ID | RunID | Key | Value | State
```

So what I'm trying to do in Power BI using Dax query is to get value for a key. (It's possible to have duplicated Key-Value pairs but I can take a top one)

```
NEWCOLUMN =
VAR tmp =
    FILTER (
        Table2,
        AND ( Table2[RunID] = Table1[RunID], Table2[Key] = "KEY_I_NEED" )
    )
VAR tmp2 =
    CALCULATE ( VALUES ( Table2[Value] ), TOPN ( 1, tmp ) )
RETURN
    tmp2
```

Right now I'm getting the error:

> "The expression refers to multiple columns. Multiple columns cannot be
> converted to a scalar value."

and couldn't get it to work the way I need.

Comment: Are you trying to add a column to `Table1` or are you trying to create a new table or something else?

Comment: @AlexisOlson I'm trying to add it to Table1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is only one *distinct* value (duplicates are fine) then you can use a lookup:

```
NEWCOLUMN =
    LOOKUPVALUE(
        Table2[Value],
        Table2[RunID], Table1[RunID],
        Table2[Key], "KEY_I_NEED"
    )
```

If there are multiple distinct values, then you can use a max:

```
NEWCOLUMN =
    CALCULATE(
        MAX( Table2[Value] ),
        Table2[Key] = "KEY_I_NEED"
    )
```

The above implicitly matches `RunID` (assuming that's the columns the tables are related on).

---

There are plenty of other ways you could do this using various combinations of functions like `TOPN`, `MAXX`, `RELATEDTABLE`, `VALUES`, and so forth, but these aren't likely to be simpler or more efficient than what I've suggested.

Comment: Thank you, @Alexis Olson. The second solution worked for me since I have multiple distinct values.